# How to update new child in one to one relationship?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

How can I add child only with existing object with loosing the data

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void add_hotspot(int pano_id, JSONObject j_hotspot) {

    Query query = ssf.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Panoramas where pano_id= :pano_id");

    query.setParameter("pano_id", pano_id);

    List list = query.list();

    List<Panoramas> panorama = (List<Panoramas>) list;

    Panoramas panoramas = panorama.get(0);

    Set<Hotspot> hotspot_set = new HashSet<Hotspot>();

    try {

        Hotspot hotspot = new Hotspot();
        hotspot.setPitch(Float.parseFloat(j_hotspot.getString("pitch")));
        hotspot.setYaw(Float.parseFloat(j_hotspot.getString("yaw")));
        hotspot.setSource_id(Integer.parseInt(j_hotspot.getString("target_id")));
        hotspot.setView_type("Description");
        hotspot_set.add(hotspot);      
        panoramas.setHotspot(hotspot_set);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Session session = ssf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(panoramas);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();    
}
```

Comment: If you want update, why are you trying to create new? And what is wrong with this code? Are you just sharing with us a nice thing you've come up with?

Comment: Yes.This code replacing the existing data.could you explain with simple example to update new child in the existing object

Comment: Have you tried to call a `getHotspot` by any chance?

Comment: No.In my relation table it replaced.

Comment: Hi.Thank you so much..you are right.am creating the new one instead of adding.thanks for you help